# Thin error message

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

When I run   `ruby  filename.rb`, the thin webserver startsup but when I try to view the (Sinatra) application on localhost:4567 I'm getting this error message. Googling it revealed nothing.  Does anyone know what I might do to get past this?

```
gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/connection.rb:39:in `block in new': undefined method `associate_callback_target' for #<Thin::Connection:0x00000100fc7500> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/connection.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/connection.rb:36:in `new'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:1430:in `event_callback'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:815:in `block in eventable_read'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:812:in `times'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:812:in `eventable_read'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:369:in `block in crank_selectables'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:369:in `each'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:369:in `crank_selectables'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:324:in `block in run'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:318:in `loop'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:318:in `run'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/pr_eventmachine.rb:64:in `run_machine'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
    from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
    from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1350:in `run!'
    from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
```

The code is from a book Cloning Internet Applications in Ruby. It's happening with each of its demo applications...

**Route code**

```
get '/' do haml :index end

post '/' do
  uri = URI::parse(params[:original])
  custom = params[:custom].empty? ? nil : params[:custom]
  raise "Invalid URL" unless uri.kind_of? URI::HTTP or uri.kind_of? URI::HTTPS
  @link = Link.shorten(params[:original], custom) 
  haml :index
end

['/info/:short_url', '/info/:short_url/:num_of_days', '/info/:short_url/:num_of_days/:map'].each do |path|
  get path do
    @link = Link.first(:identifier => params[:short_url])
    raise 'This link is not defined yet' unless @link
    @num_of_days = (params[:num_of_days] || 15).to_i
    @count_days_bar = Visit.count_days_bar(params[:short_url], @num_of_days)
    chart = Visit.count_country_chart(params[:short_url], params[:map] || 'world')
    @count_country_map = chart[:map]
    @count_country_bar = chart[:bar]
    haml :info
  end
end

get '/:short_url' do 
  link = Link.first(:identifier => params[:short_url])
  link.visits << Visit.create(:ip => get_remote_ip(env))
  link.save
  redirect link.url.original, 301
end

error do haml :index end

def get_remote_ip(env)
  if addr = env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
    addr.split(',').first.strip
  else
    env['REMOTE_ADDR']
  end
end
```

Comment: What does the route code look like?

Comment: I updated the OP with more code.

Comment: This is a EventMachine issue; the maintainer of EventMachine [Aman Gupta](https://github.com/tmm1) recommends upgrading the EventMachine gem (from 0.12.10 as in your case, to 1.0.0) in this [github issuecomment](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/328#issuecomment-7567583). Worth giving it a shot. I tried to reproduce the error with 0.12.10 version, but couldn't as the gem installation failed. Thin works fine on one of my apps with EventMachine 1.0.0.

Comment: From the comments on the linked issue, it looks like ruby version has a lot to do with who does and doesn't see the bug. I'm seeing it with Ruby 1.9.2 and trying to bring up my dev machine to a newer ruby to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the *Cloning Internet Applications with Ruby* book. I tried running the code  in the GitHub repository, and barring for a few changes (due to changes in Sinatra) I can run it successfully. Perhaps you can try the answer given by Prakash Murthy, to upgrade to EventMachine 1.0.0 but I'm running the same version as you are (0.12.10) and that doesn't give me any problems.

If you drop me an email directly we can figure this out (and update Stack Overflow later).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using Ruby 1.9.2. Both versions of Eventmachine (0.12.10 and 1.0.x) raised this problem. Following a tip in the linked Github issue, I switched to Ruby 2.1.1 and re-bundled; that installed Eventmachine 1.0.3 and the problem went away.

(This whole thing involved a lot of yak shaving for me, involving updating my Mac to Mavericks, blowing away a lot of obsoleted libraries, and reinstalling Xcode and Homebrew - hopefully it's simpler for others.)